# Rules regarding commas and semicolons

Tags: grammaticality

As such, the central management objectives of this study are: to determine whether site XXXXX should be considered a non-site or, if not, provide NRHP eligibility recommendation; and to identify and assess project impacts to site XXXXX.

I'm 99% sure the colon is used incorrectly, but what about the commas and semicolon?

Comment: Can you tell us why you think the colon seems incorrect, and what your doubts are about the commas and semicolon?

Comment: The colon is incorrect (I think) because they used "are" before it. 

It should read, "There are two central management objectives: to determine..."

The commas and semicolon may be technically correct, but the first comma seems unnecessary. I think it should read, "There are two central management objectives of this study: to determine whether site XXXXX should be considered a non-site or if not, provide NRHP eligibility recommendation; and to identify and assess project impacts to site XXXXX."

I'm still not sure about the semicolon in that case though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may help to look at *BBC Bitesize*:

Semicolons can help to simplify lists by showing which items are grouped together.

Here, a colon introduces the list and semicolons indicate which parts of the list are grouped together:

You will need to bring the following: sleeping bag, pillow, and pyjamas for the overnight stay; water bottle, waterproof jacket, sweatshirt, and walking boots for the afternoon trek; and a swimming kit for the river activities.

[BBC Bitesize - How to use semicolons in a list](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/topics/zr6bxyc/articles/zhntng8)

From this point of view your sentence is correct. The colon introduces a list of two items separated by a semicolon. The second item is simple (*to identify and assess ...*). The first item (*to determine or provide ...*) is more complex, containing commas that are subservient to the semicolon and full stop that define the limits of the item.